# Let a be a unit in a ring R. Describe the ring R' = R[x]/(ax-1)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let a be a unit in a ring R. Describe the ring R' = R[x]/(ax-1)

Here we are adjoining a multiplicative inverse of an element to the ring R. 
I know every element in R' has the form (a$^{-1}$)$^k$ where r $\in$ R and k is a non negative integer.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: show that the canonical map $R \to R'$ has a section $R' \to R$, given by $x \mapsto a^{-1}$. (First, define a map $R[x] \to R$, and show that it factors through the quotient.)

You're adjoining an inverse to something which already has one. If there is any justice in the world, you should get the same ring back, shouldn't you?

Comment: I understand why R' should equal R by your last statement. I dont understand how your hint relates to the conclusion. Could you explain more? I know that the canonical map sends b -> b + (ax+1)

Comment: @sarah The canonical map is the composite $R \to R[x] \to R'$, where the second map is the quotient map. In particular it doesn't make sense to say that the canonical map sends $x$ anywhere, because $x$ is not in $R$. 

In order to prove that two things are isomorphic, you need to compare them using a map. You have one map, the canonical map $R \to R'$, which you suspect is an isomorphism. To show that this is true, you have to construct its inverse. The goal of the hint is to show you how to explicitly construct the inverse.

Comment: @sarah (Remark: it is NOT true that $R'=R$. What is true is that $R$ and $R'$ are isomorphic, via the natural map $R \to R'$. Isomorphic and equal are two different things: the first one requires a map, while the second one requires an inclusion. The sets $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are isomorphic, but they are not equal.)

Comment: so x is in R'? we want to define a map that sends x to a$^{-1}$.

for the map R[x] to R. Could it just be r0 + ...rn where each ri is the coefficient of the polynomial?

Comment: @sarah Well $R'$ contains the class of $x$ modulo $(ax-1)$, which I also denoted $x$ by abuse of notation. But yes, you want to send $x$ to $a^{-1}$. In order to do this, show that there is a unique map $R[x] \to R$ sending $x$ to $a^{-1}$ (this is pretty much the property which characterizes a polynomial ring: you can send a free variable to anything you want). Then show that $(ax-1)$ is contained in the kernel (in fact, it's the whole kernel, but never mind this), and therefore the map $R[x] \to R$ factors as $R[x] \to R[x]/(ax-1) \to R$. The second map is the one you want.